# Физтех с большой буквы?

Tags: выбор-слов, названия

Физтех, как Физико-технический институт с большой буквы?

Answer (score 1):

Это название, значит пишется с прописной буквы.

Московский физико-технический институт (государственный университет) (МФТИ), неофициально **Физтех** — один из ведущих российских вузов ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82))